# getting error in a simple api request using node JS request lib

Tags: node.js, google-api, request

I'm trying to preform a simple API request with node:

```
const request = require('request');
request({
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=MYAPIKEY',
  json: true
} , (error , response , body) => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

and getting the following error on console:

```
{
  error_message: 'You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account',
  results: [],
  status: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'
}
```

while on the browser the request completes successfully with the exact same request.

I activated my billing account with no change.

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some digging I found out that new rules have been applied by google, and in order to get the response you need to activate billing **on every project** through the console.
First you need to set up billing account for google cloud platform, which won't charge you unless you want to. after you done that, you need to go to your specific project and activate billing for that project, which wasn't very intuitive to understand.